# play a sound when the exception error occurs in python

Tags: python

I want to get some data from another website using python `requests`. But sometimes the server does not reply correctly.

I used `try` and `except` in my code and want to play a sound in the except block.

I have already tried the following:

```py
import winsound

try:
    #do something
except:
    winsound.Beep(400,400)
```

This code does not work when I executed it. It just raises the exception.

Comment: Are you really sure the exception is raised inside your `try` block? Since you do not raise it again in your `except` block, you should not see it

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with my full code. Your solution works. I must check it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure, that winsound really works and otherwise show us the full code.

This example uses the cross platform compatible [bell character `\a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) and works:

```py
import sys

def bell():
    sys.stdout.write('\r\a')
    sys.stdout.flush()

def riskyFunction():
    raise Exception("I am an exception")

try:
    riskyFunction()
except Exception as e:
    bell()
    raise e
```

Comment: how is that gonna play a sound?

Comment: @BlueRineS it uses the bell character, I have edited this into my answer

Comment: Wow. So writing a specific character to stdout actually makes the machine produce a sound?

Comment: Yes. If you have a Unix system, you can verify this with `echo -e '\a'`.

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows**

```
import winsound
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz
winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

Where freq is the frequency in Hz and the duration is in milliseconds.

**On Linux and Mac**

```
import os
duration = 1  # seconds
freq = 440  # Hz
os.system('play -nq -t alsa synth {} sine {}'.format(duration, freq))
```

**Try this**

```
import winsound
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz

def makeSound():
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)

def makeException():
    raise Exception()

try:
    makeException()
except Exception as e:
    makeSound()
    raise e
```